# How to add space between rows and sum up automatically in Excel

Tags: excel

let's say that I have a table like the below:

```
|   | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |   |
|---|---------|---------|---------|---|
| A | 22      | 12      | 3       |   |
| A | 5       | 6       | 12      |   |
| A | 19      | 9       | 13      |   |
| A | 22      | 43      | 31      |   |
| B | 7       | 12      | 23      |   |
| B | 5       | 5       | 8       |   |
| B | 35      | 78      | 9       |   |
| B | 45      | 1       | 8       |   |
| C | 34      | 56      | 0       |   |
| C | 22      | 1       | 14      |   |
| C | 13      | 46      | 45      |   |
```

and that I'd need to transform it into the below:

```
|   | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |   |
|---|---------|---------|---------|---|
| A | 22      | 12      | 3       |   |
| A | 5       | 6       | 12      |   |
| A | 19      | 9       | 13      |   |
| A | 22      | 43      | 31      |   |
|   | 68      | 70      | 59      |   |
|   |         |         |         |   |
| B | 7       | 12      | 23      |   |
| B | 5       | 5       | 8       |   |
| B | 35      | 78      | 9       |   |
| B | 45      | 1       | 8       |   |
|   | 92      | 96      | 48      |   |
|   |         |         |         |   |
| C | 34      | 56      | 0       |   |
| C | 22      | 1       | 14      |   |
| C | 13      | 46      | 45      |   |
|   | 69      | 103     | 59      |   |
```

How could I obtain the desired effect automatically?

There would be *n* empty rows after each group and the sums of each column within the group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Subtotal feature of Excel. Subtotal is in the "Data" tab of the ribbon. To automatically add the totals between groupings. I don't think it adds the blank row. If you absolutely need the blank row, then I can generate some VBA that will work.

Comment: The bank space would be needed in order to have a more clear visual environment.
Given that the number of  rows of each group could change day by day, and that the table could be populated with many groups, would that be any chance to make a Macro that makes the Subtotal for each column of each group automatically? I used myself the Subtotal feature you're mentioning, but it can be very time consuming.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have attempted so far?

Comment: I should have read your first answer better. I found that Group by rows and  Subtotal is what I needed.